# Updating an Andriod-Mobile Application

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

Is there a way to update my published app's first version if I have lost my signed apk, keystore and .pepk files? My laptop crashed - my data was not backed up. The only thing I have is that 1.aab file from Google play - I don't know how can it be helpful in my case.What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's published you can download the apk in the Google Play Console. APK extraction tools are there, as well as (dex2jar), what you'd have to do is rename file to zip, extract the contents, use dex2jar, change bundle ID/version or whatever in the manifest, resign it, then repackage the APK.

Those are the gist of it, high overview steps, you can easily find a detailed version on the internet or on SO if you look deeper.

You can use google console to recreate your signing stuff, keys, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no chance to do that. You just learned how important a backup can be.